# Is sockets accept() return descriptor blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: c, sockets

Is the socket descriptor returned by the `accept()` function in blocking or non-blocking mode?

Answer (score 6):

From `man 2 accept`:

```
   int accept4(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr,
               socklen_t *addrlen, int flags);
```

And further down:

```
   If flags is 0, then accept4() is the same as accept().   The  following
   values can be bitwise ORed in flags to obtain different behavior:

   SOCK_NONBLOCK   Set  the  O_NONBLOCK  file  status flag on the new open
                   file description.  Using this flag saves extra calls to
                   fcntl(2) to achieve the same result.
```

Thus, I would expect a socket descriptor returned from accept() to be in blocking mode.

Answer (score 5):

No, sockets do not inherit non-blocking status from the listening socket. You have to make it non-blocking yourself.

Comment: According to MSDN: "The newly created socket is the socket that will handle the actual connection and has the same properties as socket `s`, including the asynchronous events registered with the `WSAEventSelect` function", where `s` is the listening socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB Yes, but it doesn't explicitly mention non-blocking status, so I would still make the new accepted socking non-blocking to be on the safe side.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I recall from my reading of Unix Network Programming vol.1 that socket inherit *socket* properties but not properties at the file descriptor level.

Answer (score 3):

Windows will transfer the non-block property to the returned socket

Linux won't, you have to explictly set the socket to non-blocking (easiest way is calling accept4 with the non-block flag)

Answer (score 1):

From [accept(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html):

> On Linux, the new socket returned by accept()  does  not  inherit  file
> status  flags such as O_NONBLOCK and O_ASYNC from the listening socket.
> This behavior differs from the canonical  BSD  sockets  implementation.
> Portable  programs  should not rely on inheritance or noninheritance of
> file status flags and always explicitly set all required flags  on  the
> socket returned from accept().

So it seems that Linux is the odd one out. BSD and Windows do seem to inherit the non-blocking behaviour.